# Code::Blocks: g++ not found

Tags: compiling, c++, code-blocks

Recently I have installed Code::Blocks IDE on my Ubuntu 12.10. The following error appears when I try to run or compile any code written in there:

```
Compiling: /home/sabbir/first.cpp
/bin/sh: 1: g++: not found
Process terminated with status 127 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most likely you are simply missing a compiler.

Get one by installing `build-essential` package.

Typing `sudo apt-get install build-essential` into terminal is one of the easiest ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to install g++ c++ compiler using synaptic package manager

Comment: Synaptic is no longer installed in Ubuntu by default.  It might be better to suggest one of the methods more readily available such as apt-get or software centre eg "sudo apt-get install g++"

Answer (score 0):

There is no c++ compiler! You should install gcc c++

```
apt install gcc-c++
```

After installing c++ compiler it will work